# Named temporary files with Cython

Tags: cython

I am looking for `C` analog of the `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()` function in order to use it in parallel `Cython` code without `GIL`. In theory `tmpnam` function could do the trick:

```
from cython import parallel
from libc.stdio cimport FILE, tmpnam, fopen, fclose, fwrite
from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef save_obj(string obj):
    cdef char* fname
    cdef FILE* cfile
    with nogil, parallel.parallel():
        fname = tmpnam(NULL)
        cfile = fopen(fname, "wb")
        fwrite(obj.data(), 1, obj.size(), cfile)
        fclose(cfile)
```

However, for some reason it still does not work, as I get the following error during the compilation:

```
    with nogil, parallel.parallel():
        fname = tmpnam(NULL)
                      ^
------------------------------------------------------------

testc2.pyx:9:23: Converting to Python object not allowed without gil
```

I do not understand, where this `python` object comes from, as the function comes from `C`.

Can someone explain me, why it still requires the `GIL` for `tmpnam`, and how could I overcome this problem?

Comment: `tmpnam` is explicitly not thread safe (it writes into a static buffer for a start - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145048/c-c-thread-safety-of-tmpnam and elsewhere for more details). Therefore, trying to use it in a parallel section would be a very bad idea. If you don't need the filename `tmpfile` might be a better option. If you need the filename and are on unix look at `mkstemp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of Cython's information for importing native functions like those in the C standard library, comes from information in `pxd` files, which are analogous to header files. Cython bundles several `pxd` files for the C standard library headers, including `stdio.pxd` [link](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libc/stdio.pxd). This is what you're importing from on the second line of your code.

If you check the link, you'll see that `tmpnam` isn't defined in the bundled `stdio.pxd`, and so Cython's guessing that you're using a Python name in that context. You can still import the function, but you'll have to provide a prototype:

```
cdef extern from "stdio.h" nogil:
   char* tmpnam(char*);
```